# Website displays as gibberish when linked from Facebook in IE

Tags: html, css, facebook, wordpress

I recently had a server switch but this happened on occasion prior to my server being switched.  When I link a post on my facebook fan page, occasionally it will just show the link with no description and look odd.  Apparently, the reason is because it's rendering the page like this in IE...

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why it's doing that?  It's a wordpress blog and here are my top lines...

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!-- HTML 5 -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
```

Thanks for any help!

replies:

Tried changing DOCTYPE as requested, no luck.  I also removed the meta tag and same thing. I am using http://web-sniffer.net/ with IE and it seems 50% of the time it loads normal, the rest looks like gibberish.  Will keep updated based on replies

reply 2:

Here is my exact header in php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cantarell' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" >
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="animated_favicon1.gif" >
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); if(is_home() || is_front_page()) { echo ' - '; bloginfo('description'); } else { wp_title(); } ?></title>

<?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
</head>
```

Added this as my new header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Still no luck, it shows as gibberish.

---

I am beginning to wonder if it's server side because it seems to work fine on my local drive (though to be fair I'm not connected to the live DB), and I changed the theme to the basic wordpress theme and it still had the error

Comment: tried removing that meta tag?

Comment: Maybe examine the response headers too

Comment: Trying changing DOCTYPE to this <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

Comment: Can we see the rendered header? Php output

Comment: try using this:
'<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8" />' , if it still fails, try finding a better sniffer....

Comment: I was wondering if my DB was corrupt but it displays on Chrome and FF just fine all the time.  It's just IE that has this issue.  I am still lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I know what happened.  It appears to be a compression issue on the server using WP-Super Cache.   I turned it off and it appears to be better